Is this torsion submodule sequence an exact sequence?

Let $0\rightarrow M'\xrightarrow{f} M\xrightarrow{g} M''\rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence. Then, the sequence $0\rightarrow T(M'')\rightarrow T(M)\rightarrow T(M')$, where T is the torsion submodule (prove that it is well-defined) is exact. Provide an example where the last arrow is not surjective.

The sequence will be well-defined, since $T$ is an homomorphism of modules that restricts the sequence.
Let $0\rightarrow M'\xrightarrow{f} M\xrightarrow{g} M''\rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence. We apply $T$ to $f$ and $g$. Then, $T(f)$ is injective because $f$ is injective and $T$ is a restriction. Moreover, $T(g) \circ T(f) = 0$ since $g\circ f=0$.
Now, we want to see that $Ker(T(g)) = Im(T(f))$. By (b), if $x\in T(M)$, then $x\in Ker(T(g))$. Therefore, $Im(T(f))\subseteq Ker(T(g))$.
On the other hand, let $y\in Ker(T(g))\subseteq Ker(g) = Im(f)$ and since $f$ is injective, it implies that $y\in Im(T(f))$. Therefore, $Ker(T(g))\subseteq Im(T(f))$.
I need some indications for the example.

So you need to find a submodule $M'\subset M$ such that there is a torsion element in $M/M'$ which does not come from a torsion element in $M$. Try to take $\mathbb{Z}$ as your base ring, and $M$ a torsion-free abelian group, if that helps.

Hint: You can find $M$ and $M'$ torsion-free with $M''$ a torsion abelian group.

Could it be that the sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies what I want?
